# Angular 6 with material design mat-toolbar problem

Tags: angular, angular-material

i was making a little tutorial with angular 6 and material. My code:

HTML:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>Angular 6 Mean Stack Sample</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app-module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ListComponent } from './components/list/list.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './components/create/create.component';
import { EditComponent } from './components/edit/edit.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListComponent,
    CreateComponent,
    EditComponent,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the html section i get this error from my ide:

ng: 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

When i start the programm everything works but i get nothing on my screen. Error from the web-console is:

Error: Unexpected module 'MatToolbarModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

I reinstalled everything, started the project from scratch but nothing helped. I would be great if anyone could help me,

thank you,

Tom

Comment: You have `MatToolbarModule` in `declarations`, it should be in `imports` as it's a module.

Comment: My fault, Looks like i was blind, i tried everything but this.... Thank you all for your help. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Move your module `MatToolbarModule` to `imports` array from `declarations` array. `Modules` can only be imported, where as `components` are declared.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ]
```

Comment: The old mistake. Sometime i cannot see the wood for the trees.